# Visual studio code reports docopt import error while there are no problems in bash terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, docopt, pylance

Just installed extension ms-python.python  Visual studio code reports in regard of my code in main.py

```
Import "docopt" could not be resolved from source 
{
"resource": "/home/XXXXXXXXX/main.py",
"owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#0",
"code": {
    "value": "reportMissingModuleSource",
    
"severity": 4,
"message": "Import \"docopt\" could not be resolved from source",
"source": "Pylance",
```

}

Why i can import module normally and vscode extension [ms-python.python](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python&ssr=false#qna) can't?

if i run `python`

```
 Python 3.9.6 (default, Jul 30 2021, 16:35:19) 
 [GCC 7.5.0] :: Anaconda, Inc. on linux
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more
 information.
 >>> import importlib
 >>> docopt_spec = importlib.find_loader("docopt")
 >>> found = docopt_spec is not None
 >>> found
 True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the bash terminal, you are using the Anaconda. Make sure you have select it as the python interpreter or install the `docopt` package into the environment which you are using.

The Status Bar always shows the current interpreter.

[image]

[official docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment)

Comment: thanks! i have to just select proper  env by click!